# Windows keeps running out of memory and all programs report using only KB

Tags: windows-7, memory

I'm running updated Windows 7 x64 as a non admin on a laptop with 16GB of memory.

Some weeks ago I ran out of memory - too many VMs I guess - and since then Task Monitor and Process explorer report that all the programs are using between 1-900KB of memory. Only pslist reports more realistic numbers.

I would love that to be true - somehow all Windows programs being as efficient as stuff running in DOS in 80s - but I don't think it's true.

Also even though task manager reports physical memory around 60% full I keep getting errors that I should close Firefox to free up memory or similar.

A restart doesn't solve the problem.

[image: Here is a screenshot of task manager]

Here is what pslist shows:

```
All memory values are displayed in KB.
Abbreviation key:
   Pri         Priority
   Thd         Number of Threads
   Hnd         Number of Handles
   VM          Virtual Memory
   WS          Working Set
   Priv        Private Virtual Memory
   Priv Pk     Private Virtual Memory Peak

Name                Pid Pri Thd  Hnd   Priv        CPU Time    Elapsed Time
....
firefox           24160   8  82  992 568540     0:07:46.770     1:09:33.583
opera             32160   4  17  336 148564     0:07:03.355     1:06:07.044
opera             21428   4  16  359  56736     0:00:07.113     0:49:13.945
opera             44440   4  16  419  45620     0:00:03.354     0:07:55.235
taskeng           43300   8   4   87   3048     0:00:00.093     0:03:33.948
opera             39080   4  15  404  80276     0:00:04.976     0:01:40.097
opera             43128   8  14  381  72096     0:00:02.870     0:01:32.598
WmiPrvSE          44988   8   9  236  32200     0:00:00.592     0:01:23.079
opera             23500   8  14  256  26112     0:00:00.327     0:00:20.235
opera             31008   8  16  286  43256     0:00:01.513     0:00:11.748
opera             35872   8  20  440  72836     0:00:02.012     0:00:05.974
pslist            40572  13   1  194   4232     0:00:00.390     0:00:01.438
```

Comment: Do you have an admin account on the laptop? Can you check the processes for other users?

Comment: Wonder what Resource Monitor and the Memory tab show when this occurs. Include a screen shot of that but perhaps it's all standby memory or something. Look up RamMap free app too I think it's sysinternals.

Comment: The "priv" column of pslist is showing the private committed virtual address space of each process, while the "Memory (priv...") column in TM is showing the physical RAM that's underneath that. So it is entirely reasonable that the latter is a subset of the former. pslist's "priv" for Firefox does match the "commit size" shown in task manager, near enough, as it should - they're the same counter.